# Question about matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have been learning about matrices in my math class and I am confused as to how exactly they work.

Take this example:

$\left(\begin{array}{c c c c c | c}
1 & 4 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 4\\ 
3 & 5 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 24\\ 
-8 & -5 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \end{array}\right)$

I tryed to format it the best that I could.

How exactly would I find the

1.) Pivot Column

2.) Pivot Row

3.) Entering Variable

4.) Exiting Variable

5.) Pivot Element

I feel like I have a general grasp on the concept, however, I would like to make sure that I fully understand what I'm doing from a secondary source first.

Comment: I've formatted the matrix as I assumed it should be; did I get it right?

Comment: I haven't come across this kind of terminology before.. Entering and exiting variables? A matrix is just a 2D array of numbers. Maybe you're talking about systems of equations?

Comment: @pjs36 yes, you have gotten the formatting correct

Comment: I would also like to add that I know that the pivot column is the first row and the pivot row is the top row, however, I am disconcerted with the rest

Comment: For an explanation with examples see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pivot_element).

Comment: ^Thank you, although I am still confused as to what the entering and exiting variables are

Answer (score 0):

Your first step should be to put the matrix in Row Echelon Form or Reduced Row Echelon Form. Then you may apply the definitions you have.

I am not familiar with the terminology for 3 and 4. However if they are interrelated with pivots then row reduction is the road your should travel.